# Normal cone of a vertex

Tags: convex-optimization

could someone please help me on the following exercise:

Let $P ⊂ \mathbb{R}^n$ a polyhedron and $v$ a vertex of $P$. Show: $\textrm{dim}(N_P(v))=n$

Comment: What approaches have you tried to solving this problem? Also, are there any extra assumptions on $P$?